# Fake IE7 or IE8 from IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I know it sounds a bit crazy but my client is using IE6 and I have so many problems with that browser, is there any way if the website is opened with IE6, let it act like it is IE7 or IE8?
P.S: I'm not crazy :)

Comment: not crazy but maybe a bit delusional :-)   Man I hope someone has a good answer for this!

Comment: tell your client to upgrade or fire him. STOP SUPPORTING IE6

Comment: `<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.goatse.cx/"><![endif]-->` but sadly that website isn't anymore what it was. :(

Answer (score 7):

If you control the website:

Add the [IE8.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) script to it. It's not a fix-all solution, but it will bring it **much** more in line with standard browsers.

If you don't:

No.

Comment: wow, i had no idea this even existed.  If i had any more upvotes left today, id be all over it.

Comment: Sweet!!  the site says it's in beta.  How stable is this beta?  Thanks for the info.

Comment: and if js is off? Ooops... broke

Comment: @Mark: It's been in beta for at least a year and a half. I've never had stability problems, and I've been using it since then.

Comment: @corymatthews: Indeed, no JS, no fix. But how many people are technical enough to turn off JS and non-technical enough to still be using IE6? Personally, I don't support IE6, other than this script (because it's nearly zero effort to do). Supporting it with non-standard settings is totally out of the question.

Comment: @Macha: unfortunately a lot of people are still **forced** to use IE6.  Too many IT managers got stuck in the "don't touch/upgrade it if it's still working" ideology.  I completely understand the thought behind it but in todays world of constantly finding serious security issues that just doesn't cut it. (+1 for the js find btw)

Comment: @Chris: If they suscribe to "don't touch if it's still working", they will have left the default settings on, including javascript, meaning this script works for them.

Answer (score 0):

Um. Let's think about this: No.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate CSS document for IE6, that allows you to compensate for the issues that you have with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

make your client download chrome frame, that'll work totally. you could also use the XUA Compatible <meta> element to make IE emulate whatever